# Wordpress: is there a SHORTCODE to output the Registration Form in frontend?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Is there a Native Wordpress Shortcode to to output the Registration Form in frontend?

If answer is 'no', then is there a way to add a code in function.php to enable this shortcode?

I know that there are plugins to get this, but those plugins are membership plugins which add a lot of features which I don't need. I just need the form in the frontend.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend Gravity Forms with User Registration addon https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/. It's really easy to setup and manage. You can even add extra fields for users etc.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no native WordPress shortcode to do what you would like. You need to do some development.

Possible duplicate question with detailed answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-to-display-wordpress-user-registration-form-in-front-end-of-the-website)